# android table row mouse listener

Tags: android, tablerow

I want to use mouse listener for table row, wants to use mouse button up and mouse button down button implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your recent questions I think you should be using a `ListView`.

It will be easier to create a `View` to display multi-column output inside a `ListView` than it would be to re-implement `ListView` on top of `TableLayout`.

Comment: I fixed it by myself using 

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  int viewId= v.getId();
  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

   v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pressed_application_background_static); 
  }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
   v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
   handleEvent(viewId);
  }else{
   v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
  }
  return false;
 }

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer.  Please post the solution as an answer the question and then accept it as other people finding your question might not find it in a comment.